# Can we restrict the width of a NSMutableAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsmutableattributedstring

I have a string Ex: *Arya said* **"We must find a solution"** *yesterday.* Here I want to restrict the width of the text in bold ("We must find a solution") to 100, but others must not be shortened. So I added it as 3 different `NSMutableAttributedString`s appended together and set this to a `UILabel`. I want to know if I can restrict the width of one of these strings alone.
I tried the following :

`let mutableString = "We must find a solution"`

1. `mutableString.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 30))`
2. `mutableString.draw(with: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 10), options: .truncatesLastVisibleLine, context: .none)`
3. `mutableString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 100, height: 40), options: [.truncatesLastVisibleLine,.usesFontLeading], context: .none)`

But none of them worked. I want to reproduce the `UILabel` `.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail` for a `NSMutableAttributedString`. Am I doing something wrong here, is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What should happen if the bold string is longer than 100? Do you want to cut it off at the end? Can you add some pictures showing the end result for different bold string lengths?

Comment: Ya I want the last part to be truncated like this : This is a truncat....

Comment: "But none of them worked" - what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I wanted the resulting NSMutableAttributedString  to be  : "We must find.... so I tried the methods 1,2,3 listed above but the string returned is always the non truncated version. I want to reproduce the UILabel's .lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail for a NSMutableAttributedString

Comment: How about using three `UILabel`s next to each other? Now you can use `.lineBreakMode` for the bold text. You can line them up in a horizontal `UIStackView` to make it look like one string.

Comment: No I think it works seperately but not when appended to other `NSMutableAttributedString`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using three `UILabel`s in a `UIStackView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let label1 = UILabel()
    label1.text = "Arya said"
    label1.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)

    let label2 = UILabel()        
    label2.text = "\"We must find a solution\""
    label2.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
    label2.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    
    let label3 = UILabel()
    label3.text = "yesterday"
    label3.font = UIFont.italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
    
    let stack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label1, label2, label3])
    
    stack.axis = .horizontal
    stack.spacing = 4
    
    label2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        label2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
    ])
    
    self.view.addSubview(stack)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        stack.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
    ])
}
```

output:

[image]

Comment: In this case will we  be able to allow multiple lines of text, in case the text is dynamic?

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected outcome?

Comment: You can set `label2.numberOfLines = 0` to get multiple lines.